# ADK DemoKit - RT-ADK connection Trouble ... USB disconnected

Tags: android, usb, arduino, adk

I'm trying to test the Android ADK using the DemoKit app and the RT-ADK board. The DemoKit works about one minute long. However, after that, the run loop of the DemoKit stops. At that time, the program put 
the message, "D/vold(117): USB disconnected" to the logCat, and the TX LED of the arduino board 
(RT-ADK) flashes twice.
After that, when I click the "back" button of the android terminal, lying android picture appears
short time on the terminal and perhaps, it says, the USB is disconnected. 
Did anyone experience the similar situation?  and I'm glad if some one show me how to fix this situation.
I'm using the XPERIA SO-01C, android 2.3.4.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, it is the right solution, but when I provided power from USB AC adopter to the Arduino board, istead of providing power from PC USB connector, the usb resetting has not occured more than several minutes. The page http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardADK may say the reason.

wrong?:   [android-terminal] --- usb-cable --- [arduino-mega-adk] --- usb-cable --- [PC]

right?:   [android-terminal] --- usb-cable --- [arduino-maga-adk] --- usb-cable --- [AC adopter]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar situation trying to drive a normal servo using code derived from DemoKit running on Arduino Mega ADK.  When on Arduino USB power, like you, it would disconnect for no apparent reason.  I tried powering off of a 9V battery and it worked better but the symptoms eventually returned so badly that if I put a torque on the servo the USB would disconnect. I checked the voltage of the battery and while connected underload it had sagged to 4.8V, and with no load it was reading 7.2V. I then went to a 7.7V (2S) 1300 mAHr (25C) battery and it has worked fine so far.  It looks like USB circuitry is sensitive to under-voltage during high current draw when servo is moving at high rate or high torque/load.  It looks like enough to trigger USB disconnect logic without more catastrophic effects on Arduino and Android ADK.